# countable vs uncountable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

In Principles of Mathematical Analysis(Rudin) , 2.14 themorem said A be the set of all sequences whose elements are the digits 0 and 1, then A is uncountable.

I understand the proof of these theorem.

My question is that we can represent all natural number to binary number
such like 4 = 100. In that case we can consider the natural numbers as the set of sequence whose elements are the digits 0 and 1. By doing so, natural numbers are not countable sets.

What's the point I missed??

Comment: The natural numbers correspond to **finite** sequences of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In that case we can consider the natural numbers as the set of sequence whose elements are the digits 0 and 1.

"Sequence" here refers to an infinite string of $0$s and $1$s, also known as an infinite binary string.

Each natural number has a *finite* representation as a binary string.

What's uncountable is the set of all *infinite* binary strings.

Comment: I think that we can increase natural number infinitely many tiems. So in that case, can we get infinite binary strings??

Comment: @wlaudsla123, no.  There are indeed infinitely many natural numbers.  But each of these numbers still has only a *finite* representation as a binary string.  Just like how each has only a *finite* representation as a decimal string.

Comment: AHH, I get the point!!!  Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: @wlaudsla123, great, glad to help!